# Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'confirm.orderTotal'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am having problems with confirming the pending payment of my Ionic `3` `application`.

Whenever i push my button `"Paid",` it produce this `error`, `"Reference.push failed:` first argument contains undefined in property `'confirm.orderTotal'..."` my intention is to bring my pending orders to the confirm `table` in my Firebase if I clicked on the `button.`

Can anyone help me with this error? Thanks!

[My Firebase Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBrBt.jpg)

## My typescript coding

```
export class CashierconfirmPage {
  nav: any;

  confirmItem = {} as orderItem;
  confirmItemRef$: FirebaseListObservable<orderItem[]>

  orderItemRef$: FirebaseListObservable<any>

    constructor(public cart_data: CartData, public navCtrl: NavController, 
      public navParams: NavParams,
      private database: AngularFireDatabase,) {

      this.orderItemRef$ = this.database.list('pendingorders');

      this.confirmItemRef$ = this.database.list('confirm');
    }

    addConfirmItem(confirmItem: orderItem){

      this.confirmItemRef$.push({
        // Ordermenu: this.cart_data.getCart(),
        orderTotal: this.confirmItem.orderTotal,
        orderNumber: this.confirmItem.orderNumber
      }); 
          }

}
```

## My HTML

```
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Pending payment orders</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

```
    <h2>Ordered Items:</h2>
    <li>
        <ul *ngFor="let ordermenu of item.Ordermenu">{{ordermenu.itemName}}</ul>
    </li>

    <div>
        <input type="text" ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="confirmItem.orderNumber" placeholder="{{item.orderNumber}}">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="confirmItem.orderTotal" placeholder="{{item.orderTotal}}">
    </div>

    <button (click)="addConfirmItem(confirmItem)" ion-button clear small icon-right color="dark">
        Paid
    </button>

</ion-item>
```

Comment: Verify if all field has values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hello, my English may not be correct, I'm from Brazil and I'm using Goolgle translator, sorry."

About your problem, I was facing the same, and I was able to solve it.
The Firebase does not accept undefined and yes null as empty form. You should add "|| null".

Ex:

```
addConfirmItem(confirmItem: orderItem){
  this.confirmItemRef$.push({
    // Ordermenu: this.cart_data.getCart(),
    orderTotal: this.confirmItem.orderTotal || null,
    orderNumber: this.confirmItem.orderNumber || null
  }); 
}
```

I hope I have helped and also help other people who go through this same problem.
Hugs!